# r Retain row names with order()

Tags: r

I want to produce output that shows my df sorted by the number of NAs in each row (as in the `df_rows_sorted_by_NAs` column below) but that keeps the original row name/number (`df` col). The **combination** would look like column 3 below:

```
# df_rows_sorted_by_NAs    df                  desired_output
# Row   1 :  38            Row  442  :  37     Row  3112 :  38 
# Row   2 :  38            Row  3112 :  38     Row  3113 :  38
# Row   3 :  37            Row  3113 :  38     Row  442  :  37
# Row  18 :  30            Row  1128 :  30     Row  1128 :  30
```

I get the first output with this:

```
# Sort df by num of NAs
df_rows_sorted_by_NAs <- df[order(rowSums(is.na(df)), decreasing = TRUE), drop = FALSE, ]

# View obs with >=30 NAs
for (row_name in row.names(df_rows_sorted_by_NAs)) {
  if (rowSums(is.na(df_rows_sorted_by_NAs[row_name,])) >= 30) {
    cat("Row ", row_name, ": ", 
        rowSums(is.na(df_rows_sorted_by_NAs[row_name,])), "\n")
  }
}
```

I get the second output with this:

```
for (row_name in row.names(df)) {
  if (rowSums(is.na(df[row_name,])) >= 30) {
    cat("Row ", row_name, ": ", rowSums(is.na(df[row_name,])), "\n")
  }
}
```

I tried `drop = FALSE` for `order` but got the same result. Any suggestions on how to keep the row names when I create the new df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3)
b<- c(1, NA, 3)
c <- c(NA, NA, 3)
d <- c(1, NA, NA)
e <- c(NA, 2, 3)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d, e)
df

df <- df[order(rowSums(is.na(df)), decreasing = TRUE),]
df
```

gives

```
  a  b  c  d  e
1 1  1 NA  1 NA
2 2 NA NA NA  2
3 3  3  3 NA  3
```

then

```
  a  b  c  d  e
2 2 NA NA NA  2
1 1  1 NA  1 NA
3 3  3  3 NA  3
```

and then
    df[rowSums(is.na(df)) >1,]

```
  a  b  c  d  e
2 2 NA NA NA  2
1 1  1 NA  1 NA
```

Is the actual question how do you put "Row:" in front?

```
paste0("Row ", row.names( df[rowSums(is.na(df)) >1,]), ": ",
               rowSums(is.na(df)))
```

Gives you the vector with the strings, you can make that print vertically but that's a different question than getting the sort done.

Answer (score 0):

The `tidyverse` package is good for these tasks:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

An example dataframe:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Length, ~Width, ~Mass, ~Date,
  10.3, 3.1, 0.021, "2018-11-28",
  NA, 3.3, NA, "2018-11-29",
  10.5, NA, 0.025, "2018-11-30"
)
```

With package `dplyr`, you can create an ID column and "number of NAs" column with `row_number()` and `rowSums`. Of course, if you already have a row ID column, then you can remove `ID = row_number()` from mutate:

```
df %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number(), noNAs = rowSums(is.na(.)))
```

... results in ...

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Length Width   Mass Date          ID noNAs
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <int> <dbl>
1   10.3   3.1  0.021 2018-11-28     1     0
2   NA     3.3 NA     2018-11-29     2     2
3   10.5  NA    0.025 2018-11-30     3     1
```

... adding select by ID and noNAs, arranging by noNAs (in descending order):

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number(), noNAs = rowSums(is.na(.)))%>%
  select(ID, noNAs) %>%
  arrange(desc(noNAs))
```

... results in ...

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     ID noNAs
  <int> <dbl>
1     2     2
2     3     1
3     1     0
```

Finally, if you wanted to filter for rows with more than 30 NAs, then:

```
df %>% filter(noNAs > 30)
```